# Change Perpective to 45 Degree while playing Video in VirtualDub

Tags: video, video-editing, virtualdub

Is there a filter/way to change the perspective to 45 degree **while playing the video**? It does not have to be very polished. (I am not looking for rotating video in X and Y directions, I am looking to rotate it in Z direction. Consider the video going back/front on your monitor as it plays).

This kind of video effect is fairly common in software/product promo videos (e.g. Apple).

Here is a screenshot of what I am trying to get.

[image: perspective]

Is there any other alternative to achieve this?

Comment: This looks like builtin "perspective" filter.

Comment: does not look like it works that way. Can you please elaborate.